# debugfs is not available in network namespace

Tags: linux-kernel, namespaces, filesystems

So I'm creating a network namespace:

```
% uname -r
4.15.0-rc8+
% ip netns add ns1
% ip netns exec ns1 mount
```

At this point I'm expecting to see all the same FS as I'm having on the host, however I don't see `debugfs`. Is there a special reason it is not mounted?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the debugfs mount being set as unbindable.